# Closed-form expressions of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(an) e^{-bn^2}}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Does anybody know if there's a closed-form expression of this series?
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(an) e^{-bn^2}}{n^2}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are strictly positive. It's easy to see that it's absolutely convergent, but I can't really find an expression for it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take the derivative with respect to $b$. Write $\sin^2(an)$ using complex exponentials. Then sum the series in terms of [theta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function). If the result can be integrated up analytically remains to be seen (probably not). Another possibillity is to try to write $\sin^2(an)$ in terms of complex exponentials and try to look for a Fourier series which has the given coefficients.

Comment: You have an "i" as your index, but it doesn't occur anywhere in the sum. Did you mean "n"?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it should be n. It has been edited.